# PHP curl sending message to Node.js returns no result

Tags: php, curl, websocket, socket.io

I wanted to implement websockets to a complex web system to synchronize data properly. The idea was that all clients may make ajax-calls, php handles those calls, may edit data on a database and on success the php-backend sends some data to a websocket-server. That websocket server then sends the data to all subscribed clients, which may be interested in the data.

So far clients can subscribe to the websocket server (socket.io) but I can't figure out how to make php send messages to the websocket server.

So far my websocket server looks like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const credentials = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('C:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.key/server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('C:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.crt/server.crt')
};
const app = require('express')();



// var server = require('https').Server(app);
let server = require('https').createServer(credentials, app);
let io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(3000);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("connected");
    socket.emit('test', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('some other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

    socket.on('subscribe', function(room) {
        console.log('joining room', room);
        socket.join(room);
    });

    socket.on('unsubscribe', function(room) {
        console.log('leaving room', room);
        socket.leave(room);
    });

    socket.on('send', function(data) {
        console.log('sending message');
        io.sockets.in(data.room).emit('message', data);
    });
});
```

And my php-calls look like this:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$dbHandler = \services\DBHandling::getInstance();


$data = [
    "subscribe" => "room3",
    "message" => "evacuate nuclear reactor block B !"
];
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$curl = curl_init("http://localhost");

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,['Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)
]);

curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_PORT, 3000);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_string);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ($status != 200) {
    print_r([
        'Error',
        $status,
        curl_errno($curl)
    ]);
}
curl_close($curl);
```

The php-backend only needs to send messages to the websocket server and doesn't need to receive any.

Comment: Any errors? Can you be more specific about what is not working? Lot there... For all I know it's your firewall.

Comment: have you got logs in nodejs when you call from php ? What is the error code and error returned to PHP ? Which curl error code ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make your php and your node communicate over HTTP.

You already have express installed in your node application so let's define a little API

Define a `middleware` to ensure that is your php calling the node `API`

```
/** 
 *  Secure the HTTP calls from PHP
 *  Return a 403 (forbidden) if no token given
 * */
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // Do your logic to secure your API if your node application is visible from the internet
    // You don't want malicious people to send event as your php ;)
    if(false) {
        res.sendStatus(403);
        return;
    }

    next(); // it's ok let the process continue
});
```

Define a simple route that answer on `GET` http://localhost:3000/your/endpoint

```
app.get('/your/endpoint', function(req, res) {
    io.sockets.emit('update');

    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

If you want to use the body of the HTTP request, you could use library like `body-parser` that allow you to do stuff like below. This route answer at `POST` http://localhost:3000/post/example

```
/** Enable the parsing of request body */
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/post/example', function(req, res) {
    let body  = req.body,
        event = body.event,
        data  = body.data || {};

    if(undefined === event) {
        res.sendStatus(400);
        return;
    }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks :)
Any idea how to secure the API via a middleware?

Comment: It depend the time you have to secure it. If you want a simple solution you can share a static token, or share a generation token rule between node & php. And then just check the token on the request before let it access to your API. If PHP and node are on same server you can check that the request come from `localhost`. Otherwise you can share a certificate, but I don't know so much this solution :) Glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

WebSocket is a complex protocol that you will not be able to use with raw PHP. Here are some links, just for information:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455

---

If you want a communication between your PHP and WebSocket server, then you can use a PHP library that helps you in that way. Here is a little list of known PHP library that do the job:

- https://github.com/amphp/websocket-client
- https://github.com/Nekland/Woketo
- https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet

For more information, please checkout their documentation.